# Stop floating divs from wrapping

Tags: html, css-float, word-wrap

I want to have a row of divs (cells) that don't wrap if the browser is too narrow to fit them.

I've searched Stack, and couldn't find a working answer to what I think should be a simple css question.

The cells have specified width. However I don't want to specify the width of the row, the width should automatically be the width of its child cells.

If the viewport is too narrow to accomodate the rows, then the div should overflow with scrollbars.

Please provide your answer as working code snippet, as I've tried a lot of the solutions I've seen elsewhere (like specify width: 100% and they don't seem to work).

I'm looking for a HTML/CSS only solution, no JavaScript.

```css
.row {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.cell {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">a</div>
  <div class="cell">b</div>
  <div class="cell">c</div>
</div>
```

At the moment I'm actually hard coding the width of the row to a really big number.

Comment: did one of the answers below work for you?  I'm not having any success with any of them.

Comment: I just tried all the answers, and none worked for me. The problem was I needed to center two floated left divs, and prevent the one on the right from being pushed below to the left after the window is resized.

Comment: @Nicholas I think my example is *exactly* what you're looking for, I came across this same problem today. The drop-down menus overflow but the first tier do not wrap.

Answer (score 112):

The CSS property `display: inline-block` was designed to address this need. You can read a bit about it here: http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/

Below is an example of its use. The key elements are that the `row` element has `white-space: nowrap` and the `cell` elements have `display: inline-block`. This example should work on most major browsers; a compatibility table is available here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=inline-block

```
<html>
<body>
<style>

.row {
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.cell {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">a</div>
    <div class="cell">b</div>
    <div class="cell">c</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add `<!DOCTYPE html>` or `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">` to the top of the HTML to have IE not default to quirks mode.

Comment: Note: I had my cell-type divs set up with float:left, and this forced the computed style to be block, instead of inline-block.  Took a while to figure out, so thought it best to share that.

Comment: This doesn't work with the last cell being `float: right`, does it?

Comment: This isn't really an example of how to keep *floated* divs from wrapping -- you just unfloated the cells.  I have a layout with some left and right floats, so I can't do away with the floats to solve the wrapping issue.

Comment: Haha, fair enough. It's a pedantic distinction, but you are right. I didn't solve "stop floated divs from wrapping", I solved the asker's *real* question "how do I make my layout work". To answer the former: I'm reasonably sure there is no way to prevent floated divs from wrapping. Just like the asker, you will need to find a different way to encode the layout you are describing.

Comment: once "white-space: no-wrap" added to the container, you might want to add "white-space: normal;" to the children elements or else their content will overflow their own box.

Answer (score 33):

You want to define `min-width` on row so when it browser is re-sized it does not go below that and wrap.

Comment: This'd work even with floats. I think that's the real answer.

Comment: Agree with @Danon - this works whereas the inline-block introduced vertical alignment issues.

Comment: Depends on your needs. This does stop floated divs from wrapping when the page is resized, but the asker stated "I don't want to specify the width of the row, the width should automatically be the width of its child cells". Manual width specification requires some duplicated work, since you need to compute the total width of the row. Even worse, if your cells are variable width (say, because they are sized to a line of text inside them) then computing the total may be impractical or impossible.

Comment: -1; This goes against what the OP specifically stated in his question, namely NOT having to specify width. +1 to Calvin's comment above.

Answer (score 5):

After reading John's answer, I discovered the following seemed to work for us (did not require specifying width):

```
<style>
.row {
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.cell {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 100px;
}
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello </div>
    <div class="cell">hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello </div>
    <div class="cell">hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This fixed a problem I was having with draggable divs on the iphone. When the divs had more than one word in them and they were dragged to the edge of the screen the div would wrap so that there was a word on either line. Anyway `overflow: visible;
    white-space: nowrap;` Did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: It worked because he unfloated the cells.  Not really a solution to keep actually floating divs from wrapping

Answer (score 2):

The only way I've managed to do this is by using `overflow: visible;` and `width: 20000px;` on the parent element. There is no way to do this with CSS level 1 that I'm aware of and I refused to think I'd have to go all gung-ho with CSS level 3. The example below has 18 menus that extend beyond my 1920x1200 resolution LCD, if your screen is larger just duplicate the first tier menu elements or just resize the browser. Alternatively and with slightly lower levels of browser compatibility you could use CSS3 media queries.

Here is a full copy/paste example demonstration...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>XHTML5 Menu Demonstration</title>
<style type="text/css">
* {border: 0; box-sizing: content-box; color: #f0f; font-size: 10px; margin: 0; padding: 0; transition-property: background-color, background-image, border, box-shadow, color, float, opacity, text-align, text-shadow; transition-duration: 0.5s; white-space: nowrap;}
a:link {color: #79b; text-decoration: none;}
a:visited {color: #579;}
a:focus, a:hover {color: #fff; text-decoration: underline;}
body {background-color: #444; overflow-x: hidden;}
body > header {background-color: #000; height: 64px; left: 0; position: absolute; right: 0; z-index: 2;}
body > header > nav {height: 32px; margin-left: 16px;}
body > header > nav a {font-size: 24px;}
main {border-color: transparent; border-style: solid; border-width: 64px 0 0; bottom: 0px; left: 0; overflow-x: hidden !important; overflow-y: auto; position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1;}
main > * > * {background-color: #000;}
main > section {float: left; margin-top: 16px; width: 100%;}
nav[id='menu'] {overflow: visible; width: 20000px;}
nav[id='menu'] > ul {height: 32px;}
nav[id='menu'] > ul > li {float: left; width: 140px;}
nav[id='menu'] > ul > li > ul {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); display: none; margin-left: -50px; width: 240px;}
nav[id='menu'] a {display: block; height: 32px; line-height: 32px; text-align: center; white-space: nowrap;}
nav[id='menu'] > ul {float: left; list-style:none;}
nav[id='menu'] ul li:hover ul {display: block;}
p, p *, span, span * {color: #fff;}
p {font-size: 20px; margin: 0 14px 0 14px; padding-bottom: 14px; text-indent: 1.5em;}
.hidden {display: none;}
.width_100 {width: 100%;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<main>
<section style="height: 2000px;"><p>Hover the first menu at the top-left.</p></section>
</main>

<header>
<nav id="location"><a href="">Example</a><span> - </span><a href="">Blog</a><span> - </span><a href="">Browser Market Share</a></nav>
<nav id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="" tabindex="2">Menu 1 - Hover</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="" tabindex="2">Menu 1 B</a></li>
<li><a href="" tabindex="2">Menu 1 B</a></li>
<li><a href="" tabindex="2">Menu 1 B</a></li>
<li><a href="" tabindex="2">Menu 1 B</a></li>
<li><a href="" tabindex="2">Menu 1 B</a></li>
<li><a href="" tabindex="2">Menu 1 B</a></li>
<li><a href="" tabindex="2">Menu 1 B</a></li>
<li><a href="" tabindex="2">Menu 1 B</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="" tabindex="2">Menu 2</a></li>
<li><a href="" tabindex="2">Menu 3</a></li>
<li><a href="" tabindex="2">Menu 4</a></li>
<li><a href="" tabindex="2">Menu 5</a></li>
<li><a href="" tabindex="2">Menu 6</a></li>
<li><a href="" tabindex="2">Menu 7</a></li>
<li><a href="" tabindex="2">Menu 8</a></li>
<li><a href="" tabindex="2">Menu 9</a></li>
<li><a href="" tabindex="2">Menu 10</a></li>
<li><a href="" tabindex="2">Menu 11</a></li>
<li><a href="" tabindex="2">Menu 12</a></li>
<li><a href="" tabindex="2">Menu 13</a></li>
<li><a href="" tabindex="2">Menu 14</a></li>
<li><a href="" tabindex="2">Menu 15</a></li>
<li><a href="" tabindex="2">Menu 16</a></li>
<li><a href="" tabindex="2">Menu 17</a></li>
<li><a href="" tabindex="2">Menu 18</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I use the upvoted answer and replace `width:100%` with `width:1000px` it works for me

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I used 20K pixels for a reason, with 4K screens coming out you know there will eventually be 8K and so on, so best to work with an insanely high number to keep it working for those extra years until screens are more high-resolution than life itself. ;-)

Comment: Understood... I'm just happy I got it to stop wrapping. CSS-it drives me nuts even with F12 tools. I don't know how anyone got anything done without them.

Comment: For future reference: using a huge width/height is highly inefficient because the browser still stores an unneeded big box into memory. Set the container to `white-space: nowrap;` and the children to `display: inline-block;` as already said in other answers (or fall back to `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;`).

Comment: `main > * > * {background-color: #000;}` O_o

Answer (score 0):

For me (using bootstrap), only thing that worked was setting `display:absolute;z-index:1` on the **last** cell.

Comment: `display:absolute` is not valid CSS

Comment: Probably meant position

Answer (score -1):

I had a somewhat similar problem where a bounded area consisted of an image in a float:left block and a non-float text block.  The area has a fluid width.  The text would, by design, wrap up along the right side of the image.  The trouble was, the text began with an <h2> tag, the first word of which is the tiny word "From."  As I resized the window to a smaller width, the non-floated text would, for a certain range of widths, leave only the word "From" at the top of the wrap area, the rest of the text having been squeezed below the float block.  My solution was to make the first word of the  tag bigger, by replacing the space that followed it with this code, <span style="opacity:0;">x</span> .  The effect was to make the first word, instead of "From", "FromxNextWord", where the "x", being invisible, looked like a space.  Now my first word was big enough not to be abandoned by the rest of the text block.