# Wrapper-overflow when window is resized

Tags: jquery, html, css, resize

My site is at jrctestsite.co.nf is having sizing issues when I make the window smaller where the accordion overflows vertically. I'm wondering if someone can point me in the right direction. I think it most likely has to do with the css properties of the wrapper div but I'm not 100% sure and was hoping if a second pair of eyes could help!

Edit - Any other suggestions on how to improve the performance of my site are welcome!

Comment: Are you asking how to make it work for smaller screens? Responsive is a site wide process, involving percentages, em, and min/max CSS.

Comment: Yes, I think that's what I want to do. I used twitter bootstrap on this and I remember seeing a responsive tutorial. Should I just look into that?

Comment: plalx that worked perfectly! I realize that I should most likely work on a responsive solution but that will work for the time being!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting `white-space: nowrap;` on your wrapper element seems to do the trick, if the trick is to prevent your floated elements from wrapping ;). You can learn more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616360/stop-floating-divs-from-wrapping).