# How to make a row of divs flow in one line inside another div?

Tags: css

I have a div "container", say 400px width, with a left-floated divs inside — "box" 100px width. There are six of "box" divs so their summary width is larger than 400px which causes that line of divs to get wrapped and I get two lines, with 4 and 2 elements each. How can I make these 6 divs go in one row, one line instead of two?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop floating divs from wrapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616360/stop-floating-divs-from-wrapping)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply need `white-space: nowrap` on the parent element with `display: inline-block` on the children. [Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/EgeBuZI/1/edit)

```
  <div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
```

css:

```
.container {
  width: 400px;
  background: black;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.container > div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #555;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you continue using float: left;... If your container has a set width of 400px, then your total sum of children divs can't surprass 400px wide either.  This includes any padding, margin, or border space as well.

To answer your question simply, there are several ways...

1. Make the container 600px wide instead of 400px...
2. Make the child elements 66px wide instead of 100px...

A better option is to use percentages...

- Make the child elements 16.666667% wide.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `display: inline-block` to the children of container and also give `white-space: nowrap` to make them flow horizontally. Here is the CSS

```
#Container {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.inside {
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

and HTML

```
<div id="Container">
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
 </div>
```

Here is the fiddle for your problem http://jsfiddle.net/sgaurav/vZLWQ/

Comment: Nice, stole my answer like a boss =D

Comment: Will never do that. As a matter of fact, we answered almost at same time. I faced exact same problem about 2 days back so "white-space: nowrap" was fresh to me. This fiddle helped me about 2 days back http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/FPBWr/. I modified it to match the question asked.

Comment: It's ok...but you can see that you posted your answer after mine with the same solution. What good is that doing anyone?

Comment: When I started creating fiddle and writing answer their was only one answer that suggested to use 'display: inline-block'. Since that won't have solved query, I answered the question. Although yes my bad, I should have checked new answers already posted by time I finished writing mine.

Answer (score -1):

hope it will help you

```
 display:inline-block;
```