# How can I float a bunch of divs and still get overflow?

Tags: html, css, css-float, overflow

[Here is my jsfiddle showing my attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/JR7yL/):

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

I expect/want this to create one long row with a horizontal scrollbar.  Instead, the `box`es are wrapping to a second row when the reach the end of the `container`.  I want them to keep going.  How can I accomplish that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop floating divs from wrapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616360/stop-floating-divs-from-wrapping)

Comment: @m59 So it is.  I couldn't find that even though I looked for dupes.  I'll leave mine around for others.

Comment: Duplicates aren't necessarily hurting anything. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144608/is-a-duplicate-question-considered-a-generally-bad-or-good-thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `white-space: nowrap` on the parent and `display: inline-block` on the children. **[Live demo (click).](http://jsfiddle.net/mr4Jr/)**

```
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: In your demo the boxes have a spaces between them.  Why does this happen?

Comment: @tieTYT inline block....it's a bit technical. I'll make a demo showing you a way to fix it.

Comment: the article you linked to has info.  No need.  Thanks

Comment: @tieTYT well here it is anyway :) http://jsfiddle.net/J3vNW/ Two of the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by wrapping them in a frame using `display:table-cell`.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n9DSq/2/)

The css:

```
   #container {
  width: 300px;
  max-width:300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-x: auto;
}



.box {
  display:table-cell;
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: The fact that the height seems to change if I remove the content makes me feel uncomfortable.

Comment: @titTYT: Are you sure? I've updated the jsfiddle to remove the content: http://jsfiddle.net/n9DSq/2/

Comment: Add content to just one of them and run it.  You'll see the height grows (in firefox)

Comment: Damn, there's different behavior between Firefox and Chrome :-(