# On a web page, How can i create a horizontal scroll instead of having this wap to the next line?

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I have a bunch of columns of info that look like this:

```
<span style="width:280px;float:left">
     some stuff
<span>

<span style="width:280px;float:left">
     some stuff
<span>

<span style="width:280px;float:left">
     some stuff
<span>

<span style="width:280px;float:left">
     some stuff
<span>

etc . .
```

given that people have different browser widths, if a person has a monitor with a small width, some of the columns wind up wrapping to the next line.   In this case, i would want a horizontal scroll bar to show up and keep everything on the same line.  What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop floating divs from wrapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616360/stop-floating-divs-from-wrapping)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply place your `span` elements in a container:

```
<div>
    <span>...</span>
    <span>...</span>
    ...
</div>
```

Then remove the `float` property from your `span` elements, and instead set them to `display` as `inline-block` and give your new containing element a `white-space` of `nowrap` to prevent them from falling onto a new line:

```css
div {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 280px;
}
```

If you really insist on using the `style` property on each individual element (which is bad practice) instead of including CSS like I've used above, this would be equal to:

```
<div style="white-space: nowrap;">
    <span style="display: inline-block; width: 280px">...</span>
    <span style="display: inline-block; width: 280px">...</span>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: I feel you should explain why you replace the floats with inline-blocks. One disadvantage of your method is that you have gaps the size of a space between the spans.

Comment: @MrLister because `inline-block` elements are rendered *inline*. Floated elements are rendered as *blocks*, and are not inline. The white-space property wouldn't have any affect on non-inline elements. To get rid of the white space between the spans, there are [several things which can be done](http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block).