# On a web page, how can i have a scroll bar just for a certain section?

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

On the back of getting [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159136/on-a-web-page-how-can-i-create-a-horizontal-scroll-instead-of-having-this-wap-t) answered, I have a page that looks like this.

```
 <div style="white-space: nowrap;">
    <span style="display: inline-block; width: 280px">...</span>
    <span style="display: inline-block; width: 280px">...</span>
    <span style="display: inline-block; width: 280px">...</span>
    <span style="display: inline-block; width: 280px">...</span>
 </div>
```

This page if there are a lot of spans will not wrap and it will keep going horizontally on the page and give me a horizontal scroll bar.  Inside each span i have a html table but i am not sure that is important for question.

This works well but i have an issue when one of the spans is really long vertically and the others are short because you have to scroll down vertically to actually see that you have the horizontal scroll bar.  I am trying to figure out a way to solve this so the horizontal scroll bar is always visible on the page regardless of how vertically  long a particular span section is.

As an example, if you take  alook at trello (see screenshot below).  If you have a really long section vertically it add a vertical scroll bar JUST on that section, so the whole page doesn't need to be scrolled down.

In my case inside each span is a html table. What is the recommended way of implementing a vertical scroll bar just for that table (and not the whole page)?

[image]

Comment: `overflow: scroll` on the parent? will need to define a height/max-height

Comment: @DavidNguyen - thanks David but clearly that is not what the screenshot is doing because the vertical scroll bar only applies to that specific "column" which seems more elegant than hardcoding a maxheight on the page

Comment: umm that is exactly what is happening - the column has overflow scroll. The max height would be applied on the wrapper of the spans not on the page body.

Comment: when you say parent are you talking about the div or the span? i assumed you meant the div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `max-height` and `overflow-y` on the interior elements, and you need to set sizes on the outer elements:

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">foo</div>
    <div class="inner">bar</div>
    <div class="inner">whatever</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer {
    border: 2px solid red;
    float:left;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
}
.inner {
    max-height:100%;
    overflow-y:auto;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    width:30%;
    margin-right:2%;
    float:left;
}
```

[**Here's a working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/4cRLV/)

Comment: this is a step in the right direction but my concerns with this approach is that i have to hard code that max-height where what i really want is whatever the max height of the "current screen height" without causing a vertical scroll bar to appear.  Also, ideally again would still just want that one section to scroll like the screenshot above

Comment: Because the other sections will NEVER have more than 1 page worth of items, or you WANT the other sections to cause a scrollbar for the entire page?

Comment: The logic still works, but you will need some JavaScript to get the "current screen height". Just get that height, with something like `$(window).height()` (jQuery), and update the style with that value, as in `$('div.some_class_name_relevant_to_this_div').css('max-height', ( $(window).height() - 10) +'px');` The `- 10` is just to give you some buffer; adjust per your needs.

Comment: @ganders - i basically want it to work like trello where if a column (or table in my case) is longer than the page than there is vertical scroll bar for just that section (just like the screenshot above).  so if 3 columns are greater than the size of the screen then there should be 3 vertical scroll bars

Comment: @Ed Cottrell - see my comment to ganders.  Hopefully that clarifies my requirement a little bit more

Comment: I have rewritten my answer and provided a working fiddle. Let me know if that doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

```
body, html {height: 100%}

.what_wraps_your_span {overflow-y: scroll; max-height: 100%;}
```

Comment: what do you mean by: what_wraps_your_span.  are you talking about the div in my question or the span itself?