# Getting text to hide instead of stacking ontop

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently trying to display a navbar

```
 <div class="navigation" id="navigation">
      <a href="/">Show all</a>
      {% for item in dict %}
       <a href="/{{ item }}" >{{item}}</a>
      {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

The problem is I don't know how many items will be in the `dict` could be 5 or could be 50.

What I'm trying to do is style it so it only goes as wide as their screen is, so larger screens will see the menu populated with more on a single line and smaller screens will see less items on the line, and whatever is excess to be a toggle button that displays the rest.

I'm using bootstrap.  I've tried `word-wrap: break-word;` and `overflow-y: hidden !important` but neither of them solve my problem

Edit:
Here is a jsfiddle of the problem https://jsfiddle.net/akn5r7y5/

As you can see depending on the screen size more or less titles will be on the second line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `width` of parent element `#navigation` element to `90vw` with `overflow-x` set to `hidden`. Set `height` to `86px` `font-size` to `14px`

```
#navigation {
  border-bottom: 1px solid currentColor;
  /* Or whatever color you want */
  text-decoration: none;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding-top: 70px;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  white-space: no-wrap;
  text-overflow: clip;
  height: 86px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/akn5r7y5/1/

Answer (score 0):

Answer somewhat referenced from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11006978/5610732

You can do this with just css.

To prevent the navigation menu from breaking to the next line, you'll need to add `white-space: nowrap;` to the parent `<ul>` element, `display: inline-block;` and `float: none;` to the child `<li>` elements.

I've done up an example using the default bootstrap navbar:

http://codepen.io/dominicgan/pen/ZBxMbN/?editors=1100